# How many Expert Stages are there and how are they Unlocked?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

I've been playing Pokemon Shuffle for a while and I've gotten up to to Expert Stage 19 (Yveltal) and I've gotten an S rank on many of the main stages up to 190.

I know there are more Expert Stages to unlock, but what are the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expert stages are unlocked based on the number of main stages the player has achieved S-rank on.

As of now (version 1.2.6) there are 24 Expert Stages, those you are missing are *Mewtwo*, *Genesect*, *Chesnaught*, *Delphox* and *Greninja*.

Here below you can see which Expert Levels you haven't unlocked yet.

[image]

As the developers are still adding content and so new Expert Stages, I suggest you to check [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Expert_Stages) after each update.

Comment: As a note (as this will continue to change), each time the developers add new levels, they add expert stages as well (as there are more possible S ranks).  As of February 2016, there are [35 expert stages](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonShuffle/comments/420v8x/guide_to_sranking_stages_261300_and_ex_3335/)

Comment: @ChaseSandmann That's why I've put the update version when I wrote the answer. Anyway thank you, I've just noticed that the link was changed.